clang-format configuration to keep comments on same line as opening brace
I am using clang-format to configure my C++ code formatting with the following configuration items:
BasedOnStyle: Google
Language: Cpp
ColumnLimit: 120

Now I would like to achieve the following effect:
  foreach(const QString& value, list_string) { /// value must be latter container inclusion type
    if (value == "c") { break; }
    qDebug() << value;
  }

But clang-format changes it to:
  foreach(const QString& value, list_string) { 
    /// value must be latter container inclusion type
    if (value == "c") { break; }
    qDebug() << value;
  }


You can try AlignAfterOpenBracket. I did see other examples in the documentation that do what you're asking about. Subjectively, I strongly prefer what clang-format is already doing. The comment "hides" the opening brace a bit.

Don't use comments starting with three slashes that usually mark texts for document generators and confuse clang-format.

ok,
After I took a closer look at the CLion configuration entries, I realized that just modifying the .clang-format configuration entry is not enough (not high priority). A manual CLion is required Settings|Editor|C++|Braces Layout|Allo comment after '{'.

I use "///" because I'm used to Doxygen syntax and indeed it's a bad habit. I will correct it, thanks .

In principle there is no need to configure .clang-format in any way (based on Google styles), comments do not break lines at the right length. If you are using the CLion IDE, then you need to make the following determinations:
Settings|Editor|C++|Braces Layout|Allo comment after '{'
I think it's caused by CLion's style configuration having a higher priority than .clang-format.
FIXES THIS ISSUE
